# Regarding accessing letters of strings in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;cin>>n;//entering number of string to be inputed

    string a[n];//declaring an array of type string

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    }
    //for manipulating letters of strings
    cout<<a[0][1];
    return 0;
}
```

To access the elements of a string, we should output the result as a multidimensional array. This seems a bit counter intuitive. Could someone explain is this the right way.

```
Input
2
asfdsf
asfdsafd

Output
asfdsf
asfdsafd
s
```

Comment: I’m a bit unsure what your question is, since there isn’t an actual question sentence here. What is counter intuitive and what do you need explained exactly?

Answer (score 2):

A string is an array of characters.  So an array of strings is an array of arrays of characters.  To access the `j`th character in the `i`th string, you use `a[i][j]`.

Comment: I don't think a string is "an array of characters". To be more precise, I think a string is a "sequence" of characters.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare:

```
    string a[n]; //declaring an array of type string
```

Why?

```
ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘a’
```

Instead, you should use a `vector` of `string` and `.push_back()` each new string you add, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {

    int n = 0;
    std::cout << "enter the number of strings: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    if (n < 1) {
        std::cerr << "error: invalid number of strings.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector <std::string> a;  // vector of strings

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* read each string */
        std::string tmp;
        std::cin >> tmp;            /* into a temp string */
        if (!std::cin.eof() && !std::cin.fail())    /* validate read */
            a.push_back(tmp);       /* add string to vector */
        /* output string and first character using indexes */
        std::cout << "string[" << i << "]: " << a[i] << "  (a[" << i 
                    << "][0]: " << a[i][0] << ")\n";
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stringindex
enter the number of strings: 4
My
string[0]: My  (a[0][0]: M)
Dog
string[1]: Dog  (a[1][0]: D)
Has
string[2]: Has  (a[2][0]: H)
Fleas!
string[3]: Fleas!  (a[3][0]: F)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.